# Pass data to component using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The `ButtonList` returns a list of filtered buttons that each link to a new page. Now I want that clicked-on button to also be displayed on the linked page. I don't quite understand how to save the data inside the button (a string) and pass it to the `Button` on the linked page. I assume I can do it with state (hence the `buttonContent`), but don't know how to write the code... Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [buttonContent, setButtonContent] = useState();

  const filteredData = data.filter(item =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  );

  function handleSearch(value) {
    setSearchValue(value);
  }

  function handleButtonContent() {
    setButtonContent(!buttonContent);
  }

  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
      <StyledHeader />
      <Switch>
              
        <Route exact path="/home">
                
          <Searchbar onSearch={handleSearch} />
          <ButtonList
            data={filteredData}
            onClick={handleButtonContent}
          />
           
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home/content">
          <div>
            <Button light>{buttonContent}</Button>
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have the `onClick={handleButtonContent}` I would make it an arrow function and try using the event to change the state using the `useState` hook you've already implemented. (If I'm understanding you correctly).

So something like this:

```
onClick={e => {
    setButtonContent(e.target.value)
}}
```

and hopefully that should set the state to whatever you click on. Let me know if it works!